# How to make the car move in a path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am developing a animation in javascript where a car moves towards a person and picks but currently instead of a path I am just driving diagonally to the person with below code.

```
Car.prototype.main = function() {
      var angle = angleBetweenTwoPoints(this.target.position, this.position);
      var cos = Math.cos(degreeToRadian(angle)) * -1;
      var sin = Math.sin(degreeToRadian(angle));
      var _this = _super.call(this) || this;
      this.angle = angle;
      this.position.x += cos * this.speed;
      this.position.y -= sin * this.speed;
      if (distance(this.position, this.target.position) < 10 && this.image == GameImage.getImage("hero") ) {
        this.target.position.x = Math.random() * mainCanvas.width;
        this.target.position.y = Math.random() * mainCanvas.height;
        this.hitCount++;
        console.log(hitCount);
        ctx.fillText("points : " + hitCount, 32, 32);
         this.changeImage = true;
          _this.speed = 3;
        this.changeImageTime = Date.now() + 600; //0.5 sec from now.

        this.image = (this.image == GameImage.getImage("hero"))? GameImage.getImage("hero_other") : GameImage.getImage("hero");

      }

      if(this.changeImage){
      if(Date.now() > this.changeImageTime){
        this.changeImage = false;
        _this.speed = 9;
        this.image = (this.image == GameImage.getImage("hero_other"))? GameImage.getImage("hero") : GameImage.getImage("hero_other");
      }
    }


    };
    return Car;
  }(Actor));
```

But instaed of this I want to follow a path.I also created some grids when u click the image it logs the console which grid it is.But I am unable move the car in a path.For complete understanding the animation is in 
[animation](https://codepen.io/RKR3/project/editor/ANBVpA/).

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You have most of what you want. But rather than move from one point to the other, Create a set of waypoints that are along the path you want to follow. The start at the first and move to the second, when you get there make it the first point and the move to the next one. So on till you get to the end.

Comment: Yeah you are exactly correct.As u said I need to create the waypoints which is a pretty tricky part for me.If you don't mind could you provide a working example

Answer (score 1):

### Waypoints as a queue.

For waypoints path following you use a type of array called a queue.  As the name suggests the queue holds items that need to be used, specifically they need to be used in the order in which they arrive. The first object on the queue is the first object out (unless you push in line)

In javascript a queue is easy to implement using an array.

```
const path = {
    points : [],
    currentPos : null,
    dist : 0,
    totalDistMoved : 0,
    atEnd : false,
    addPoint(x,y) { 
        if(this.currentPos === null){ 
           this.currentPos = { x :0,y : 0};
           this.dist = 0; 
           this.totalDistMoved = 0;
        }
        this.points.push({x,y}) ;
    },
    moveAlong(dist){
        if(dist > 0){
           if(this.points.length > 1){ 
              var x = this.points[1].x - this.points[0].x;
              var y = this.points[1].y - this.points[0].y;
              var len = Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y) ;
              if(len - this.dist < dist){  
                 this.points.shift(); 
                 dist -= (len - this.dist);
                 this.totalDistMoved += (len - this.dist);
                 this.dist = 0; 
                 this.moveAlong(dist); 
                 return;
              }
              const frac =  this.dist + dist / len;
              this.currentPos.x = this.points[0].x + x * frac;
              this.currentPos.y = this.points[0].y + y * frac;
              this.dist += dist;
              this.totalDistMoved += dist;
          }else{
              this.currentPos.x = this.points[0].x;
              this.currentPos.y = this.points[0].y;
              this.dist = 0;
              this.atEnd = true;
          }
        }
     }
  }
```

To use

Add some way points.

```
path.addPoint(1,1);
path.addPoint(100,20);
path.addPoint(110,120);
path.addPoint(210,120);
path.addPoint(250,420);
```

Then for each step of the animations get a distance along

```
 path.moveAlong(10); // move ten pixels
```

and use the current position

```
 ctx.drawImage(car,path.currentPos.x,path.currentPos.y);
```

You know you have reached the end of the path when.

```
  if(path.atEnd) {
        // you have arrived
  }
```

And at any time you know how far you have moved with

```
  path.totalDistMoved
```

This is meant for animations that only play forward. It will ignore negative distances as way points are dumped when you have passed them

You will need to make some modifications if you wish to reuse the path object, or if the waypoints are being added as you go

#### A simple example.

Thing moves along at constant speed. Click on page to add more waypoints.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
function mainLoop(time){
    gTime = !gTime ? time : gTime;
    fTime = time - gTime;
    gTime = time;
    if(canvas.width !== innerWidth || canvas.height !== innerHeight){
        canvas.width = innerWidth;
        canvas.height = innerHeight;
    }else{
        ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    }
    if(mouse.button){
        if(!point){
            point = {x:0,y:0};
            path.addPoint(point);
        }
        point.x = mouse.x;
        point.y = mouse.y;

    }else{ 
         if(point){ point = null }
    }
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    var i = 0;
    while(i < path.points.length){ ctx.lineTo(path.points[i].x,path.points[i++].y)}
    ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.stroke();
    
    var i = 0;
    while(i < path.points.length){ ctx.strokeRect(path.points[i].x-4,path.points[i++].y-4,8,8)}
    
    path.moveAlong(4 * fTime / 100);
    var x = path.currentPos.x - thingPos.x;
    var y = path.currentPos.y - thingPos.y;
    thingPos.x = path.currentPos.x;
    thingPos.y = path.currentPos.y;
    drawThing(thingPos.x,thingPos.y,Math.atan2(y,x));


    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
var point;
const thingPos = {x:0,y:0};
const path = {
  points : [],
  currentPos : null,
  distAlong : 0,
  totalDistMoved : 0,
  atEnd : false,
  addPoint(x,y) { 
      if(y === undefined){
         this.points.push(x); // add point as object
         return;
      }
      if(this.currentPos === null){ 
         this.currentPos = { x :0,y : 0};
         this.distAlong = 0; 
         this.totalDistMoved = 0;
      }
      
      this.points.push({x,y}) ;
  },
  moveAlong(dist){
      if(dist > 0){
         if(this.points.length > 1){ 
            var x = this.points[1].x - this.points[0].x;
            var y = this.points[1].y - this.points[0].y;
            var len = Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y) ;
            if(len - this.distAlong < dist){  
               this.points.shift(); 
               dist -= (len - this.distAlong);
               this.totalDistMoved += (len - this.distAlong);
               this.distAlong = 0; 
               this.moveAlong(dist); 
               return;
            }
            const frac =  (this.distAlong + dist) / len;
            this.currentPos.x = this.points[0].x + x * frac;
            this.currentPos.y = this.points[0].y + y * frac;
            this.distAlong += dist;
            this.totalDistMoved += dist;
        }else{
            this.currentPos.x = this.points[0].x;
            this.currentPos.y = this.points[0].y;
            this.distAlong = 0;
            this.atEnd = true;
        }
      }
   }
}

path.addPoint(20,20);
path.addPoint(120,20);
path.addPoint(220,120);
path.addPoint(320,120);
path.addPoint(420,20);

function mouseEvents(e) {
    const m = mouse;
    m.x = e.pageX;
    m.y = e.pageY;
    m.button = e.type === "mousemove" ? m.button : e.type === "mousedown";
}
function drawThing(x,y,dir) {
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,x,y);
    ctx.rotate(dir);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.beginPath();
    var i = 0;
    while(i < thing.length){ ctx.lineTo(thing[i++],thing[i++]) };
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
  
}
const thing = [-20,-10,20,-10,22,-7,22,7,20,10,-20,10];
var gTime;  // global and frame time
var fTime;
const mouse = { x:0,y:0,button:false};
["mousemove","mousedown","mouseup"].forEach(t=>document.addEventListener(t,mouseEvents));
```

```css
canvas {
position: absolute;
top : 0px;
left : 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
click drag to add waypoints.
```

Comment: Thanks much for the detailed explanation.I got the idea of waypoints.So in my scenario I should dynamically generate the way points between the car and the target.But isn't that handled by the path finding algorithms

Comment: @Ricky The path finding algorithm is something separate and would add waypoints to a path/waypoint object. Path finding functions can be simple to very complex and are very dependent on the type of map/environment you are using.

Comment: So in my case I need a path finding algorithm right.Because otherwise how can I add way points to a path just randomly

Comment: If you don't mind could you please help me my aniamtion?